# Using Python's 'with open()' To Write a Log, How Can I Write Exceptions to my Log?

Tags: python, exception, with-statement

I'm setting up a log file for a python script being run in a command window so that there's a record of all the input and output from the script. I'm using:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
```

so that it will still save all the text it has written if an exception occurs.

However I was wondering if there might be a way to get it to log the exception as well? Basically to write one last message and then close the file as the exit function?

There seemed to be only a little documentation on with open() itself. But I wasn't sure if that means its use is limited or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not explicitly catch the exception and rethrow it:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    try:
        <do_something>
    except Exception as e:
        file.write(e)
        raise
```

The challenge comes if the exception is generator by trying to write to file.

Comment: That makes sense, I had ideally hoped for a neat bit of syntax to add on the initial line but that is loading a lot onto the function. Writing to file throwing an exception is at least a very obvious problem. This is a script I'm writing for others to use and my concern is that errors appear and they'd be unable to explain to me what happened, and the log would have no record either if I didn't add this code.