# Unexpected Indent Error at End of File

Tags: python, indentation

For some reason at the end of of my python file in IDLE I'm getting an indentation error, even though the block of code has the right amount of spacing. Also when I try to run and am told about the error, it actually highlights the whole line after the code, instead of highlighting the character before a line of wrongly indented code, as it normally does.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating where it highlights:
[image: Syntax Error Highlighting Unusual Place]

For reference, this is how looks when highlighting a clearly real indent problem:
[image: Syntax Error Highlighting Normal Place]

The code itself has problems with this form:

```
if yes.lower() == 'y': linkFiles(folders)
raw_input(iprint('= Script Finished, press enter to quit.',True))
```

and this form:

```
if yes.lower() == 'y':
    linkFiles(folders)
raw_input(iprint('= Script Finished, press enter to quit.',True))
```

Also yes, I have confirmed that I'm not mixing tabs and spaces. Just using spaces on all these lines.

I also checked about any whitespace at the end of the file, but this error occurs the same even when there's no characters whatsoever after the closing bracket. And attempting to run the script does add a newline character, but nothing else.

As per a suggestion, I did try to run it through the commandline and got essentially the same result:

```
C:\Windows\system32>python "C:\Users\ntreanor\Desktop\User Friendly Scripts\Create file links.py"
  File "C:\Users\ntreanor\Desktop\User Friendly Scripts\Create file links.py", line 135

                                                                             ^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

Comment: Try putting your cursor right after the final closing `)`, hold down Shift and hit End to select to the end of the line, then hit Delete. Finally, hit Enter to add a newline, save the file, and run it again. Does that help?

Comment: I checked that just now, but even after I delete all the whitespace the error occurs. It does generate a newline character at the end when I attempt to run the script, but nothing else is different.

Comment: What happens if you run your program through the command line instead of through your IDE? Are any errors generated?

Comment: The same error seems to be there, I ammended the response to my original post.

Comment: Are all of your parentheses closed? If memory serves right I think I have had this problem before and it was because not all parentheses were closed earlier in the code.

Comment: It was not a parenthesis, but actually a missing except block. I had an odd structure to the flow and forget to close it off when writing the script. (I've added an answer explaining the solution). Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was actually way more simple than I had thought.

I was writing a try: except: block over the whole script, basically because I'm writing to a log and I want it to spit out any exceptions I get into the log so that I can troubleshoot after the fact when people have used my script. The details of this are from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370618/using-pythons-with-open-to-write-a-log-how-can-i-write-exceptions-to-my-lo)

The problem was I got interrupted when writing the script and forgot I had added the try but not the except. So the actual error was that I was missing the whole except block. Once I even just added

```
except: pass
```

at the end, it ran fine.